# Vpp of oscillation of LCR circuit

Tags: voltage, passive-networks, gain

Edited:

I'm having a trouble to estimate Vpp of a RCL oscillation circuit. I found a peak to peak inductor voltage (Vpp_L) varies with the different combination of LC, which makes sense because the frequency (f) is different.

Then what is the relationship between Vpp_L and LC combination?

Below graph is to see the oscillation voltage of LC configuration. 
Vin = 10v
Trise = 0.1ms
f = 11kHz.

[image]

Simulation:
[image]
Vpp_L = Vout = 2V @ first wave.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but simulate around different initial conditions (C voltage, L current) and share your findings.

Comment: Not enough information.  Post your circuit and initial conditions.  It may help you to know that the characteristic impedance of an LC tank (no R) is sqrt(L/C).

Comment: I have edited my question! Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

C2 brings nothing to the party because it directly connects across the voltage source.

> Then what is the relationship between Vpp_L and LC combination?

The "ringing" waveform amplitude is due to L, C and R values. Together these form a tuned-filter with a certain damping ratio. That damping ratio is governed by L, C and R and, the lower the damping ratio, the higher the ringing waveform amplitude.

If the resistor value is low (say 1 ohm): -

[image]

You get a small amount of ringing because the damping ratio (\$\zeta\$) is 0.3536. However, if R gets bigger such as 31 ohms you get this: -

[image]

Clearly the step response is much more animated now and, at 1000 ohms you get this: -

[image]

[Interactive tuned circuit page](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html#RLC_low_pass_filter_type_2). This website also gives you the mathematical tools for working this out algebraically so, if you want instead to apply a step input where the rise time is significant you can use Laplace transforms.

Alternatively just stick with the simulation and note that broadly speaking, if you keep the product of L and C constant and vary R you can alter the ringing voltage amplitude. If you wanted to changing the ringing frequency make L or C or both bigger in value.

Comment: Hello Andy, Thanks for the response! I had a C2, because initially, I had a diode in between a voltage source and an inductor, C2 helps to reduce the high frequency noise.

What I'm interested in is that every time I changed the inductance or capacitance, I would get different Vpp max voltage. The link you shared (I found it is really useful!), have max voltage at 1V, it does not go beyond 1V. However, the Vpp changes either slope (dv/dt) of input voltage or inductance/capacitance. 

I'm curious if there is a way I could mathematically predict the Vmax. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: @JustinJungheeKim 2nd order filters start to get difficult on the math hence that's why the interactive simulators are useful. You get a difference in Vpp because the damping (\$\zeta\$) ratio changes. If you keep this value constant (\$R\cdot\sqrt{C/L}\$) then the Vpp will remain the same.

Comment: @Andyaka The source has `Rser` specified, so `C2` is not useless, but the corner frequency is much higher than the LC.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks you. this is really helpful!  I appreciate your help!